# Why Android Studio v1.2 always monitoring device

Tags: android, android-studio

Yesterday, I updated my Android Studio from v1.1 to v1.2 preview, but there is problem that I don't understand. When I open Android Studio, it is `Monitoring device...` all the time and I don't know why.

I Hope someone can tell me why. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an opened [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159382) on the AOSP issue tracker.